# BASH: syntax error near unexpected token `(' in .bashrc

Tags: bash, postgresql

I wanted to get the number of current connections to my postgresql DB. Therefor I'm using this script:

```
su - postgres -c "psql -c 'SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database;'"
```

This is working like a charm.
My next step was to modify my `.bashrc` to use the command `cntcon` to show the number of connections:

```
alias cntcon='su - postgres -c "psql -c 'SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database;'"'
```

As soon as I want to reload the `.bashrc` I get follwing error:

```
-bash: /root/.bashrc: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /root/.bashrc: line 16: `alias cntcon='su - postgres -c "psql -c $'SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database;$'"''
```

I already found following solution for similar problems on stackoverflow:

[-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626209/bash-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token)

Then I got this error:

```
-bash: alias: -c: not found
-bash: alias: SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database;: not found
```

I also tried:

```
echo "alias cntcon='su - postgres -c "psql -c 'SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database;'"'" | tee -a .bashrc.
alias cntcon='su - postgres -c psql -c SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database;'
```

But got follwoing error:

```
-bash: alias: sum(numbackends): not found
-bash: alias: FROM: not found
-bash: alias: pg_stat_database: not found
-bash: ": command not found
```

I assume there is a problem with the several escapes in the script and also I assume that I'm making a simple error.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Single quotes cannot be nested.

Comment: `'su` starts a string, and then it ends at `-c 'SELECT`, leaving the rest of the sql unknown/garbage commands as far as bash is concerned.

Comment: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically suggests how to [fix this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2026). Give it a try.

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem if you used a shell function for `cntcon` instead of an alias.